# Should there be an "a" before "ten years imprisonment"?

Tags: articles

As part of a question I had on another SE site, I stumbled upon [an article](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2019/05/hb-481-georgia-law-criminalizes-abortion-subjects-women-to-life-in-prison.html?via=gdpr-consent) which has the following sentence:

> If a Georgia resident plans to travel elsewhere to obtain an abortion, she may be charged with conspiracy to commit murder, punishable by 10 years’ imprisonment

Shouldn't the answer to *punishable by **what***? be: *by **a** 10 years imprisonment* or *by 10 years of imprisonment*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. There is an apostrophe after "years", so it means "imprisonment of ten years" - though you wouldn't actually say that, you'd say "imprisonment for ten years".

Imprisonment, like most abstracts, is a non-count noun, and doesn't take "a".

You *could* just about say "a ten-year imprisonment", where the article is licensed by the qualifier on "imprisonment" (compare "a very cruel imprisonment"), but it is not idiomatic. But the plural ending on "years" indicates that it cannot be that construction.

**Edit**: corrected "count" to "non-count" above.

Comment: What about OP's last suggestion; that looks right to me: by ten years of imprisonment.

Comment: I disagree that *a ten year imprisonment* is unidiomatic. But that's a minor point.

Comment: @Cardinal: I can't fault that, but I wouldn't say it, probably because "ten years' imprisionment" is shorter (and idiomatic, for me).

Comment: @JasonB - I'm not sure about what qualifies as "idiomatic," but I think Colin correctly points out which one we're more likely to encounter in [printed reports](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five+years%27+imprisonment%2Cfive-year+imprisonment%2C+five+year+imprisonment&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Cardinal "by ten years of imprisonment" does not sound right.  The alternates to "punishable by 10 years’ imprisonment" are "punishable by a 10 year prison sentence" and "punishable by a sentence of 10 years in prison".

Comment: Thank you for the details. I always saw the apostrophe as a sign of "ownership" (*the baker's shop*, *France's Eiffel Tower*) - in the direct sense (something belongs to something or someone) and not indirect such as "the ten years of imprisonment" (as if "imprisonment" would own the ten years)

Comment: @WoJ: it is of possession (which is a wider relationship than ownership) but you have it the wrong way round. "Ten years' imprisonment" expands to "Imprisonment of ten years" (though as I said, "for ten years" is more idiomatic).

Comment: @WoJ - See [this column about possessive time phrases](https://www.theenglishspace.com/grammar/possessives/possessive-time-phrases.html) for more information. It says: _We don't normally think of time being able to own or possess things, but we use these phrases to say that something is associated with a certain period of time._ It's a somewhat odd convention, but it's widely-used, and it won't seem so odd once you see it a few times and get used to it.